# How do I change the value of a handle in C?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dereference

I have an array of 8 arrays, where each of the 8 arrays have contain 8 ints (if the code is correct).

I was wondering how can I get each pointer in the array_of_arrays to point to a separate array?
(I tried using a pointer to the address of a pointer but couldn't get it to work)

```
int main() {
  
  int array_of_arrays[8][8];
  
  int array[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  
  *&*array_of_arrays[0] = array;


  return 0;
}
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC3By.png)

Thanks!

Comment: In a true two-dimensional array you cannot.  You need a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: Using a 64 (8*8) simple array would be an option.

Comment: `each pointer in the array_of_arrays` There is no `pointer` in `array_of_arrays`, only 8*8 `int` values.

Answer (score 1):

`int array_of_arrays[8][8];` does not declare an array of pointers. It declares an array of arrays of 8 `int`. Each of the arrays of 8 `int` is inside `array_of_arrays` and cannot be arranged to be elsewhere. You can copy data into them, but there are no pointers to set.

You can declare an array of 8 pointers to `int` with `int *array_of_arrays[8];`, and then `array_of_arrays[0] = array;` would set `array_of_arrays[0]` to point to the first element of `array`. After initializing each of the pointers, you could use `array_of_arrays[i][j]` in expressions to access elements of the arrays.

Comment: If I didn't use a pointer and kept it as int array_of_arrays[8][8], how would I copy data into them like you mentioned?